# How to fix : Cannot create a multipart form data section without body data

Tags: unity, c#

I successfully coded my game to register a player with their 'username, password, email' After Registering id like a player to fill in their username & password and have it checked by the db. Upon 'Login' i ran into this :

> "ArgumentException: Cannot create a multipart form data section without body data"

```
public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public void SignupComplete()
    {
        // Make sure nothing is blank

        if (usernameSignup.text == "" || passwordSignup.text == "" || passwordVerification.text == "" || age.text == "" || email.text == "")
        {
            return;
        }
        
        // Check if passwords match

        if (passwordSignup.text != passwordVerification.text)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Check Age

        if (int.Parse(age.text)< 13)
        {
            return;
        }

        // IF the client makes it this far, send their data to the website!

        Debug.Log("Processing Request");

        StartCoroutine(ProcessRequest(usernameSignup.text, passwordSignup.text, DATA_URL_SIGNUP, age.text, email.text));

    }

    // ERROR WHEN LOGIN  "ArgumentException: Cannot create a multipart form data section without body data"
    public void LoginComplete()
    {
        if(usernameLogin.text == "" || passwordLogin.text == "" )
        {
            return;
            Debug.Log("Please fill in all fields!");
        }

        StartCoroutine(ProcessRequest(usernameLogin.text, passwordLogin.text, DATA_URL_LOGIN));
        Debug.Log("Processing Request");
    }

    IEnumerator ProcessRequest(string username, string password, string url, string age = null, string email = null)
    {
        List<IMultipartFormSection> form = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();

            form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("username", username));
            form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("password", password));
            form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("age", age != null ? age : "0"));  //age != null ? age : "0"
            form.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("email", email == null ? "" : email));

            UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else 
            {
                Debug.Log("Signup completed!");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `List<IMultipartFormSection>`, use [`WWWForm`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html):

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.Add("username", username));
form.Add("password", password));
form.Add("age", age != null ? age : "0"));
form.Add("email", email == null ? "" : email));
UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
//...
```

See also: [POST request documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)

Comment: WWW is depreciated no ? or is it just the WWWRequest...

Comment: WWWForm is not deprecated. You should get used to looking at the documentation, it can answer these questions for you.

Comment: Sorry... yea i really should

Comment: @IyaadSaley You originally marked this as the correct answer and then un-marked it; is there something you need clarification on?

Comment: Was up late last night, might of done it by accident.

Comment: I've taken your advise and spent the entire night reading over docs... Its my first time using unity and id like to create a login system, would you mind leading me a hand if you have some spare time ? I have a PHP script that is not working as intended...

Comment: @lyaad If you need help with your login system, it should be posted as a new question. However, if you're new to Unity, I would recommend not trying to dive into login systems or anything else that requires a backend. You will be overwhelmed. Spend some time (weeks or months) learning Unity well before trying to expand into backend systems. One of the most common reasons for new developers to give up on their projects is that they try to do something too complex, get overwhelmed, and decide that game development is too difficult.